# Does using "final" keep the original reference and object alive even when reassigned via a different path?

Tags: java, final

I'm wondering if `final` truly "freezes" its reference, forcing its underlying object to co-exist with any re-assignments made  to the original reference via a different path e.g.

```
class ThingHolder{
    Thing thing;
}

class Thing{
    int i=5;
    Thing(int i){
        this.i=i;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    ThingHolder thingHolder = new ThingHolder();
    thingHolder.thing = new Thing(5);

    final Thing aFinalReference = thingHolder.thing;

    thingHolder.thing = new Thing(6); //will this now coexist with "aFinalReference"?

    //... 
}
```

Will `aFinalReference` now persist as in independent object, despite no longer being a part of `thingHolder`, and continue refering to the original `Thing` (i.e. the one whose `int` is currently 5), regardless of whatever now happens to `thingHolder`?

Comment: `final` says nothing about object lifetime or reach-ability. What would the answer be without `final`? (In the general sense, `final` merely ensures a *variable* is never assigned a different value.)

Comment: Your final (hehe) line does not change the `final` reference that is `aFinalReference`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All that `final` **really means** here is that **once you assign `aFinalReference`, you cannot reassign it**.

To answer your question of what will reference what, we'll just step through the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ThingHolder thingHolder = new ThingHolder();

    // create a new Thing (we'll call it "Thing5"),
    // and point thingHolder.thing at it

    thingHolder.thing = new Thing(5);

    // thingHolder.thing now points to Thing5

    final Thing aFinalReference = thingHolder.thing;

    // aFinalReference now ALSO points to Thing5

    // create a new Thing (we'll call it "Thing6"),
    // and point thingHolder.thing at it

    thingHolder.thing = new Thing(6);

    // thingHolder.thing now points at Thing6 instead of Thing5
    // aFinalReference, however, still points at Thing5
}
```

At the end of `main()`:

- `thingHolder.thing` will point to "Thing6"
- `aFinalReference` will point to "Thing5"

Comment: Thanks, so the answer to my convoluted, somewhat badly-worded question is yes. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstand the usage of final. Check out [the JLS § 4.5.4](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.12.4). As pst suggests, the use of final does not have an impact on the lifetime of the variable itself. Declaring a variable as final affects its scope in that final variables are available to anonymous classes that are defined within the same scope as the final variable itself.

Comment: It does *slightly* affect the usable scope, for `final` variables that are accessible from anonymous classes, like action handlers. I skipped over this entirely in my comment.